# best place to put library in magento

Tags: magento

I'm a magento developer.
I am trying to make library file which contains common function like login(id, pass), deleteDir, uploadFile() etc...
So each Controller can use this functions.

But the only file that does similar things is Helper/Data.php.
But Data.php looks like common data container file.

So which file can i put common functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create helper file (like `Helper/Mylib.php`) in your module and call the function like

`Mage::helper('mymodule/mylib')->myFunction($pId);`

Answer (score 0):

You can make the block to put common functions.